# Relating face polytopes of permutohedra to integer partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, convex-polytopes, oeis

The OEIS entries [A019538](http://oeis.org/A019538), [A049019](http://oeis.org/A049019), and [A133314](http://oeis.org/A133314), relate a refinement of the face polynomials of the [permutohedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron) (A049019) to partition polynomials (A133314) defined by multiplicative inversion of an exponential generating function (or surjections as noted in A049019 and A133314).

For example, with the Taylor series expansion of an analytic function (or formal power series, or e.g.f.)

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 \frac{x^2}{2!} + ... = \exp[a.x]$$

where $a.^n = a_n$, the series expansion of the reciprocal is formally

$$\frac{1}{f(x)}= a_0^{-1} + a_0^{-2} [-a_1] x + a_0^{-3} [2a_1^2 - a_2a_0] \frac{x^2}{2!} + a_0^{-4}[-6 a_1^3 + 6 a_1 a_2 a_0 - a_3 a_0^2 ] \frac{x^3}{3!} +  a_0^{-5} [24 a_1^4 - 36 a_1^2 a_2 a_0 + (8 a_1 a_3 + 6 a_2^2) a_0^2 - a_4 a_0^3] \frac{x^4}{4!}+ ... = \exp[Pt.(a_0,a_1,..)x]\; ,$$

and the unsigned coefficients of the partition polynomial $Pt_4(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_4)$ for the fourth order term with partitions of the integer four characterize the $P_3$ permutohedron depicted in Wikipedia with 24 vertices (0-D faces), 36 edges (1-D faces), 8 hexagons (2-D faces), 6 tetragons (2-D faces),  and 1 3-D permutohedron. Summing coefficients over like dimensions gives A019538 and [A090582](http://oeis.org/A090582).

**Question**: Is there a bijective mapping between the integer partitions and the different polytopes of the n-D faces of the permutohedra for higher dimensions?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785526/bijective-mapping-between-face-polytopes-of-permutohedra-and-partitions-of-integ?noredirect=1#comment3683907_1785526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodica Simion in "Convex polytopes and enumeration" affirms the bijection on pages 162 and 163.

Comment: See "Hopf monoids and generalized permutohedra" by Aguiar and Ardila https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07504

Comment: See also "Diagonals on the Permutahedra, Multiplihedra and Associahedra" byb
Samson Saneblidze, Ronald Umble https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209109

Comment: See also "The Hopf Monoid of Orbit Polytopes" by Mariel Supina (https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08437).